# Why does Flex/Lex reset variable of c++ code to its initial value?

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I was trying to create simple compiler using Flex and Bison with C++, but I can't understand why when Flex reaches end of file it will reset the variable that is declared in the C++ file to its initial value.

in **lex.l** file:

```
%{
    #include "HelperCode.h"     
    // ... etc
%}
%option c++
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno
%%

[\n]    { dosomething();}

// ...etc
%%
```

and the **HelperCode.h** file:

```
namespace
{
    int counter  = 0;

    //rest of code

    void dosomething()
    {
        counter++;
        cout << counter << " ";
        // here it will print the correct values based on input
        // ex: 1 2 3 4 5
    }

    void afterfinish()
    {
        cout << endl << counter;
        // but here it will print '0', like if the counter reset to 0 
    }
}
```

and in **yacc.y** file:

```
// ... etc
// ...
void main(void)
{
    Parser* p = new Parser();
    p->parse();

    afterfinish(); 
}
```

Comment: flex doesn't do that. Are you sure it's not something you're doing?

Comment: The counter needs to be in a *class*, not a namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that you put a `namespace { ... }` into a header file.

Each of your C++ translation units which includes this gets a copy of the raw text of the header file, and therefore has a **copy** of the namespace declaration.  Since the namespace is anonymous, each copy is independent; each translation unit which includes this *has its own* `counter`, as well as `dosomething` and `afterfinish`.

This is very similar to a situation in the C language of placing some static definitions into a header, like this:

```
static int counter = 0;
static void dosomething(void) { printf("%d\n", ++counter); }
static void afterfinish(void) { printf("%d\n", counter); }
```

Each C unit which `#include`-s this header gets its own counter, along with a its own private pair of functions `dosomething` and `afterfinish` which operate on it.

The lexer module operates on its own counter, and the `afterfinish` in the module which contains `main` operates on *its* own counter which is still zero.

If you want a namespace which is shared by your modules, just give it a name.

```
// header file HelperCode.h
namespace parser_stuff {
  // We no longer *define* the counter in the header, just declare it.
  extern int counter;

  // And we use inline on functions defined in the header, otherwise
  // they will now be multiply defined!
  inline void dosomething()
  {
     counter++;
     // ... etc
  }

  // non-inline function
  void afterfinish();
}


// In one .cpp file somewhere, perhaps HelperCode.cpp
#include "HelperCode.h"

namespace parser_stuff {
  int counter = 0; // One program-wide definition of parser_stuff::counter.

  void afterfinish()
  {
    // ....
  }
}
```

Of course, we now have to do

```
%{
    #include "HelperCode.h"     
    // ... etc
%}
%option c++
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno
%%

[\n]    { parser_stuff::dosomething();}

// ...etc
%%
```

Or else:

```
%{
    #include "HelperCode.h"     
    // ... etc

    // one of these: bring in a specific identifier, or whole namespace:
    using parser_stuff::dosomething;
    using namespace parser_stuff;
%}
%option c++
%option noyywrap
%option yylineno
%%

[\n]    { dosomething();}

// ...etc
%%
```

and similarly in the main module which refers to `afterfinish`.

Comment: thank you for your helpful answer, it's working now.